Bochs can't access bootloader address 0x7c00, error: physical memory read error
Recently I tried to get into OS development, but with that I also need some tools to help me debug my problems. First I tried with QEMU and GDB, but I needed to make 2 separate builds and GDB wasn't going at the same pace as QEMU. I saw a better alternative and that is BOCHS. While on my Ubuntu virtual machine BOCHS works. When I dual booted on my computer Ubuntu to not have to run it in a virtual environment I get this error when putting a breakpoint at 0x7c00 and pressing continue:
bx_dbg_read_linear: physical memory read error (phy=0x0000322f3130, lin=0x00000000322f3130)

This is the assembly code that is transformed in a floppy image, but I doubt the code here is the problem:
org 0x7C00
bits 16

;entru un valid fat 12 fisier trebuie sa declaram niste biti de pe osdev wiki FAT
;BIOS parameter block
jmp short start
nop

OEM_identifier:             db 'MSWIN4.1'
bytes_per_sector:           dw 512  ;asa cum am declarat in comenzi si in test.img
number_sector_per_cluster:  db 1    ;asa cum reiese din hex editor test.img
number_reserved_sectors:    dw 1    
number_file_alloc_tables:   db 2
number_root_dir_entries:    dw 0x00E0   ;from 0x11 location
total_sectors_logical:      dw 0x0B40   ;from 0x13
media_descriptor_type:      db 0xF0     ;from 0x15
num_sectors_per_FAT:        dw 0x0009   ;from 0x16
num_sector_per_track:       dw 0x0012   ;from 0x18
num_heads_or_sides:         dw 0x0002   ;from 0x1A
num_hidden_sectors:         dd 0x00000000   ;from 0x1C
large_sector_count:         dd 0x00000000   ;from 0x20

;extended boot record

drive_number:               db 0x00     ;from 0x024
flags_for_WIN_NT:           db 0x00     ;from 0x025
signature:                  db 0x29     ;from 0x26
volumeID_serial_num:        dd 0xF6705BF5   ;from 0x027
volume_label_string:        db '           ';from 0x02B
system_identifier_string:   db 'FAT32  '    ;from 0x036

;
; rest code down from 0x03E
;

start:
    jmp main

putstack:
    push si ;salvam registri in stack
    push ax
    push bx

.loop:
    lodsb   ;comanda loadeza byte ul de la adresa ds:si in al
            ;"ds" cate segmente in fata si "si" offset
            ;segment*ds+si
    or al,al
    jz .done    ;daca flag z este 0 adica am ajuns la sfr string iesi
    
    mov ah,0Eh  ;pentru tty print string 
    int 10h     ;video mode
    
    jmp .loop   ;repeta pana la iesire

.done:
    pop ax  ;pop pentru a returna valoarea din stack in ax
            ;clarificare: stack ul nu stie cine este in capul lui
            ;pop "param" ia un parametru unde returneaza valoarea din cap
    pop si
    pop bx
    ret

main:

    mov ax,0        ;push 0 in ax
    mov ds,ax       ;nu putem accesa direct cei doi registri
    mov es,ax       ;segment memory registers

    mov ss,ax       ;la fel ca mai sus
    mov sp,0x7C00   ;inceputul stackului creste in josul programului prin conventie

    ;citeste de pe floppy
    ;BIOS-ul seteaza dl cu numarul drive ului(drive number)
    mov [drive_number],dl

    mov ax,1        ;LBA = 1, al doilea sector de pe disk
    mov cl,1        ;1 sector de citit
    mov bx,0x7E00   ;datele trebuie sa fie dupa bootloader
    call disk_read  ;citim

    mov si,msg  ;punem in "si" adresa stringului(nu valoarea)
                ;am spus ca "si" este offset un offset nu mai mare de 64kb
    call putstack
    
    hlt     ;halt procesor

;
;Error handlers
;
floppy_error:
    mov si,error
    call putstack
    jmp wait_key_for_reboot

wait_key_for_reboot:
    mov ah,0
    int 16h         ;interrupt pentru a astepta o tasta apasata
    jmp 0FFFFh:0    ;adresa inceputul bios ului

.halt:
    cli     ;cpu poate sa treaca de ce am scris 
            ;cli opreste orice fel de inerrupt
    hlt     ;ca sa nu riscam il blocam intr-un loop infinit


;
;   LBA to CHS converter 
;   ax continue input ul adica valoarea LBA
;   -cx[bits 0-5]: numarul sectorului
;   -cx[bits 6-15]: numarul cilindrului(track)
;   -dh: numar heads
;
lba_to_chs:
    ;sector = (LBA%num_sector_per_track)+1
    ;head = (LBA/num_sector_per_track)%num_heads_or_sides
    ;cylinder = (LBA/num_sector_per_track)

    push ax
    push dx

    xor dx,dx   ;set dx la zero
    div word [num_sector_per_track] ;ah = LBA/num_sector_per_track, al=rest pentru byte
                                    ;pentru word catul este in ax si restul in dx

    inc dx
    mov cx,dx   ;punem in cx dx+1 pt ca e incrementat

    xor dx,dx
                                    ;catul precedent este in ax
    div word [num_heads_or_sides]   ;impartim la num_heads

    mov dh,dl
    mov ch,al
    shl ah,6
    or cl,ah

    pop ax
    mov dl,al
    pop ax
    ret

;
;citeste un nr de sectori
;Parametri:
;   -ax :LBA address
;   -cl :numar sectori sa citesc
;   -dl: numar drive
;   -es:bx: adresa memorie unde pastram date
;dupa conventie INT 13,ah=2(read disk sectors)
;de bios variabilele de mai sus vor fi folosite
;
disk_read:

    push ax ;salvam registri care se vor schimba
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push di

    push cx     ;salvam temporar cx pe stack ca sa nu fie schimbat de converter
    call lba_to_chs
    pop ax

    mov ah,02h  
    mov di,3    ;pentru ca floppy disk-urile se strica foarte repede trebuie 
                ;sa rulam de un numar de ori ca sa ne citeasca de pe disk
                ;chiar si dupa 3 ori cum am setat in "di" s-ar putea sa 
                ;nu mearga asa ca dam cu banu

retry:
    pusha   ;push all orice registru
    stc     ;set flag carry deoarece dupa aceasta operatie bios ul va returna
            ;flag carry 0 astfel ca atunci cand acesta este zero inseamna ca operatia
            ;a avut succes
    int 13h
    jnc done

    ;read failed
    popa    ;pop all
    call disk_reset

    dec di
    test di,di
    jnz retry

fail:
    ;floppy_error "di" a ajuns la 0
    jmp floppy_error

done:
    popa

    push di ;restore registri salvati
    push dx
    push cx
    push bx
    push ax

    ret

;
;   Resets disk controller
;   Parametri:
;       -dl: drive number
;
disk_reset:
    pusha
    mov ah,0
    stc
    int 13h
    jnc floppy_error
    popa
    ret


msg: db 'hello world!',0    ;mesajul
error:  db 'error has acourred while reading from disk',0

times 510-($-$$) db 0   ;dummy bytes
dw 0AA55h   ;signiture pentru bios

This is the make file:
ASM = nasm

SRC_DIR = src
BUILD_DIR = build

.PHONY: all floppybuild kernel bootloader clean always

#floppy image

floppy_img: $(BUILD_DIR)/floppybuild.img

$(BUILD_DIR)/floppybuild.img: bootloader kernel
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$(BUILD_DIR)/floppybuild.img bs=512 count=2880
    mkfs.fat -F 12 $(BUILD_DIR)/floppybuild.img
    dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin of=$(BUILD_DIR)/floppybuild.img conv=notrunc
    mcopy -i $(BUILD_DIR)/floppybuild.img $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin "::kernel.bin"

#Bootloader
bootloader: $(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin

$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin : always
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/bootloader/boot.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin

#kernel
kernel:$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin

$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin : always
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/kernel/main.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin
    
#always
#daca "/build" nu exista
always:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

#clean
clean:
    rm rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*

This is the bochs configuration file:
megs: 128
romimage: file=/usr/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-latest, address = 0xfffe0000
vgaromimage: file=/usr/share/bochs/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest
floppya: 1_44=build/floppybuild.img, status=inserted
boot: floppy
mouse: enabled=0
display_library: sdl2, options="gui_debug"

the current kernel file is completely empty so only the bootloader is present in the floppy image
This is how it looks on my desktop. I don't know if the crashing has anything to do with my current problem because if I press step or continue the crashing popup disappears.

The installed packages for bochs are: bochs, bochs-sdl, bochsbios, vgabios.

aparrently because of a new update bochs pushed it kinda messed with the romimage on Ubuntu as a quick fix instead of using the latest i used the legacy bios so instead of:
romimage: file=/usr/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-latest, address = 0xfffe0000

just put:
romimage: file=/usr/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-legacy

this solve the issue of not being able to access the beggining of the bootloader but it doesnt fix the app from crashing every 5 seconds. for that i just press the wait button apparantly even if it says that its not responding text will still be printed to the bios.
